# trying to download zip file in R 4.0, works in windows, linux but not in MacOS..."HTTP status was '400 Bad Request"

Tags: r, http, download, http-status-code-404

I am going bonkers as I switched from a windows tablet to my macbook pro earlier today and cannot seem to run the identical (seemingly trivial) command in R4.02, namely to download a zip file located at the following link:
http://askebsa.dol.gov/FOIA%20Files/2018/Latest/F_5500_SF_2018_Latest.zip

I used the R base syntax of:  download.file(url, destfile= "xyz.csv") and it worked as expected in windows, but when I run it in Mac,  I get 'HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'.  I can manually download it in Mac, I just need to do it in R.

Any ideas if this a cache, cookie or some other issue?